# How to insert an article with a special number type in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

Most article has the following format:

```
@article{~~~,
    author  = {~~~},
    title   = {~~~},
    journal = {~~~},
    volume  = {1},
    pages   = {10-20},
    month   = {Jan.},
    year    = {2018},
}
```

However, the article I want to refer has the pages from 033542-1 to 033542-15.

If I type

```
    pages   = {033542-1-033542-15},
```

then the result is:

[image]

How can I change this as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, the question was tagged with `biblatex`, where

```
pages  = {{033542-1}-{033542-15}},
```

works if you use Biber and gives

[image]

This trick only works in the `pages` field, if you want to give specific page numbers in the postnote you need

```
\cite[\ppno~{033542-12}\bibrangedash{033542-14}]{sigfridsson}
```

---

Since you use `IEEEtran.bst` you could try

```
pages  = {{033542\dash1}-{033542\dash15}},
```

and define

```
\newcommand{\dash}{-}
```

in your document.

Comment: I am using \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} and \bibliography{IEEEabrv,references}. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Danny_Kim Aha. In that case you are not using `biblatex` as your tagging suggests, but plain old BibTeX. Please add these details to your question and change the tagging appropriately.

Comment: Oh my god, it works.

Comment: Thanks to you, I can do!! using \newcommand{\PPP}{033542-} and pages = {{\PPP}1-{\PPP}15}.